# Как получить доступ к элементу radioButton, который НЕ выбран?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.5

Здравствуйте! Пишу маленькую программу для тестирования. За основу взял код из книги Зиборов В.В. - Visual С# 2012 на примерах. На форме имеется label1, radioButton1 ... radioButton7 и две кнопки button.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // Внешние переменные:
        int CorrectAnswer = 0;  // Количество правильных ответов
        int WrongAnswer = 0; // Количество неправильных ответов
        String[] MassiveCorrectAnswers = new String[100];
        String[] MassiveWrongAnswers = new String[100];
        int NumberOfCorrectAnswer;  // Номер правильного ответа
        int ChosenAnswer;  // Номер ответа, выбранный студентом
        System.IO.StreamReader Reader = new System.IO.StreamReader
            (@"Путь к файлу\...\Название файла.txt",
            System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
        // Тут пропущен код, который считывает файл и выводит на форму
        // Выясняем, какой ответ - правильный:
        NumberOfCorrectAnswer = int.Parse(Reader.ReadLine());

        void SwitchChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RadioButton Switch = (RadioButton)sender;
            var tmp = Switch.Name;
            // Выясняем номер ответа, выбранный студентом:
            ChosenAnswer = int.Parse(tmp.Substring(11));
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
            if (ChosenAnswer == NumberOfCorrectAnswer) CorrectAnswer++;
            if (ChosenAnswer != NumberOfCorrectAnswer)
            {
                // Счет неправильных ответов:
                WrongAnswer++;
                // Запоминаем вопросы с неправильными ответами:
                MassiveWrongAnswers[WrongAnswer] = label1.Text;
                // Тут ошибка
                MassiveCorrectAnswers[WrongAnswer] =
                    radioButton[NumberOfCorrectAnswer].Text;
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

В общих словах: значение `NumberOfCorrectAnswer` считывается из файла, значение `ChosenAnswer` получаем через обработчик событий.
Мы сравниваем их, если они не равны, добавляем в массив `MassiveWrongAnswers[]` вопрос, в котором ошибся пользователь, а в массив `MassiveCorrectAnswers[]` нужно добавить правильный ответ. Как обратиться к `radioButton[i]` (`i` - случайное число), если свойство `Checked = false`?

IDE - Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

Comment: Upd: Решил проблему сам - создал массив динамических radioButton. Тему можно закрывать.

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        RadioButton[] radioButton;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            radioButton = new RadioButton[8];
            int t = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
            {
                radioButton[i] = new RadioButton();
                radioButton[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 120 + t);
                this.Controls.Add(radioButton[i]);
                t += 40;
            }
        }
    }

Answer (score 1):

```
var radioButton = this.Descendants<RadioButton>().Where(x => x.Name.Contains(id) && !x.Checked).FirstOrDefault();
```

где id - ваше случайное число.

Answer (score 1):

> На форме имеется `radioButton1` ... `radioButton7`
>   Как обратиться к `radioButton[i]` (`i` - случайное число)

Вместо этого чуда сделать нормальный массив контролов и обращаться к нему.

Если уж совсем не хочется создавать радиобаттоны программно, то можно уже готовые заранее сложить в массив (естественно, надо будет перечислить все 7, а не `...`):

```
var rbtns = new RadioButton[] {radioButton1, ..., radioButton7};
```